# self join after selecting columns from table

Tags: mysql, sql

I want to select two columns from a table. On these 2 selected columns I want to do self-join(cross).

I have tried few queries but it gives me error:
`table1 does not exists`

```
select a.day day
     , b.id as id table1 a 
 cross 
  join table1 b 
 where a.id <> b.id 
   and table1 in (select id
                          , `day` 
                       from original_table 
                      where `day` = '2019-08-01');
```

The expected result is cross join of id's.

Answer (score 1):

You are missing a from clause and your condition for In was incorrect

```
    select a.day as day,b.id as id 
    from table1 a cross join table1 b where a.id <> b.id 
    and (a.id,a.day) in (select id,day from original_table where `day` = '2019-08-01');
```

Comment: It is still giving me error: `_schema_name.table1_` doesn't exist.

Answer (score 1):

you have to mention column name in where condition

```
 select a.day as day,b.id as id from 
 table1 a cross join table1 b where a.id <> b.id 
 and (a.id, a.day) in  (select id, `day` from original_table 
    where `day` = '2019-08-01');
```

Comment: It is still giving me error: `_schemaname.table1_` doesn't exist.